# Sails.JS findOne not returning Association

Tags: json, node.js, rest, sails.js, waterline

I have a function to find a resource based on it's geo coordinates, but the findOne method doesn't return the comments collection from the model. If I use the blueprint route to find based on ID, I get the comments along with it.

**find:id JSON**

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "text": "Some Text",
            "nomination": "551865064a5ccf41274be682",
            "createdAt": "2015-03-29T21:02:10.586Z",
            "updatedAt": "2015-03-29T21:02:10.586Z",
            "id": "55186852d21850a627292db3"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Karma Bird House",
    "address": "47 Maple Street Burlington, VT 05401",
    "geo": "44.473231,-73.217882",
    "lat": 44.473231,
    "lon": -73.217882,
    "streetImg": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x300&location=44.473231,-73.217882",
    "votes": 1,
    "createdAt": "2015-03-29T20:48:06.109Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-03-29T21:02:48.817Z",
    "id": "551865064a5ccf41274be682"
}
```

**findGeo:id JSON**

```
{
    "nom": {
        "name": "Karma Bird House",
        "address": "47 Maple Street Burlington, VT 05401",
        "geo": "44.473231,-73.217882",
        "lat": 44.473231,
        "lon": -73.217882,
        "streetImg": "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x300&location=44.473231,-73.217882",
        "votes": 1,
        "createdAt": "2015-03-29T20:48:06.109Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-03-29T21:02:48.817Z",
        "id": "551865064a5ccf41274be682"
    }
}
```

**findGeo Method**

```
findGeo: function (req, res, next) {
    Nomination.findOne({geo: req.param('id')}, function foundNomination(err, nom) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        if(!nom) return next();

        return res.json({
            nom: nom
        });
    })
}
```

**Model:**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id:{
        type:"int",
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    // Location's name
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    // Locations Lat and lon
    lat: 'float',

    lon: 'float',

    // lat,lon
    geo: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
    },

    // Location's Address
    address: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    // Number of Votes
    votes: {
        type: 'integer',
        defaultsTo: '0'
    },

    // Street View Image
    streetImg: 'string',

    // Association of comments
    comments: {
        collection: 'comment',
        via: 'nomination'
    }

  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "populate" method like so:

```
findGeo: function (req, res, next) {
    Nomination
    .findOne({geo: req.param('id')})
    .populate('comments')
    .exec(function (nom) {
        if(!nom) return next();
        return res.json({
            nom: nom
        });
    });
}
```